# Moving from Fedora to CentOS, what should I keep in mind?

Tags: centos, fedora

I am moving to CentOS from Fedora, I know they have a common base but I need to know if there are any differences in directory structure or configuration files.

Comment: Which version of Fedora are you on now? Are you planning to go to the most recent CentOS 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to CentOS 6 they should be pretty close. The biggest thing I would keep in mind is to use the EPEL repository. Fedora packages a lot more recent software then CentOS does, so moving to CentOS 6 you will want to add it in to be able to install some of the needed applications:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Same directories and configuration for example for apache?

Comment: yeah ... most of the configuration files should feel quite natural. Which version of fedora are you moving from? For example Fedora15 is a lot heavier on SystemD then CentOS6. But fedora 13/14 -> CentOS 6 is not a major jump.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend adding [RPMForge](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/) as a means to acquire packages that may not be available in the standard CentOS distribution or the Fedora EPEL repository.

Also see: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

I typically find everything I need in RPMForge, but will cherry-pick certain packages from EPEL when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I would use either EPEL or RPMForge **but not both**. If you do use both, you will run into incompatibilities and it you try to get around them you will fubar your system.